# Not opening emulator on android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

[Hi, I'm having a problem with android studio, even after starting my virtual device the option to start the app on that device does not come out, can anyone help me?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foJ0f.png)

i tried to search in android studio settings if i have deactivated something, but nothing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.